# Messagekit Navigation bar is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, messagekit

[image: My Screen looking like this]

How can i show the default or custom navigation bar ? tried everything but nothing works , It seems like nothing is on the top , its a messageViewcontroller of messagekit and couldn't find any delegate method for navigation bar , it would be nice if someone educate me about this ..

**My Code**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    messagesCollectionView = MessagesCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: CustomMessagesFlowLayout())
    messagesCollectionView.register(CustomCell.self)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
    messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
    messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
    messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self
    messageInputBar.delegate = self
    configureMessageInputBar()
    configureInputBarItems()
    updateTitleView(title: "Hanzala", subtitle: "Online")
}


import UIKit
```

extension UIViewController {

```
func updateTitleView(title: String, subtitle: String?, baseColor: UIColor = .white) {
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -2, width: 0, height: 0))
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLabel.textColor = baseColor
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    
    let subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 18, width: 0, height: 0))
    subtitleLabel.textColor = baseColor.withAlphaComponent(0.95)
    subtitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
    subtitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    subtitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    subtitleLabel.sizeToFit()
    
    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: max(titleLabel.frame.size.width, subtitleLabel.frame.size.width), height: 30))
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    if subtitle != nil {
        titleView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
    } else {
        titleLabel.frame = titleView.frame
    }
    let widthDiff = subtitleLabel.frame.size.width - titleLabel.frame.size.width
    if widthDiff < 0 {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        subtitleLabel.frame.origin.x = abs(newX)
    } else {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        titleLabel.frame.origin.x = newX
    }
    
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
}
```

}

**I want the navigation bar like this**

[image: Messagekit example navigation bar]

**Pushing ChatViewController in NavigationController**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let model = Api.Params.chatUser[indexPath.row]
    openConversation(model)
}

func openConversation(_ model: ChatUser) {
    Api.Params.inputRecieverId = model.userId
    let id = String(requestManager.instance.userID)
    let vc = ChatViewController(recieverId: model.userId, senderId: id, conversationId: "Eman-Conversation-\(id)-\(model.userId)")
    vc.title = model.username
    vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to embed the `MessageViewcontroller` inside a `UINavigationController` and use it.

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MessageViewcontroller())
```

If the controller that you're pushing `MessageViewcontroller` onto already has a `navigationController` then push the `MessageViewcontroller` into the navigational stack instead of presenting.

```
let messageViewcontroller = MessageViewcontroller()
navigationController?.pushViewController(messageViewcontroller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , I am already pushing it , check the edit

Comment: Is the navigation bar available before pushing?

Comment: basically i have hidden the default navigation bar , wanted to show the navigation bar which is visible in second pic , its from message kit official demo app , I have copied the code from there but its not working 

that update title view function is for navigation bar which i have to put on

Comment: I'm getting this same issue, except my navbar is showing but it's translucent (Meaning just the "back" button is showing in it, but my messages still go all the way to the top of the screen). Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @Eric i am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @TaimoorArif I don't remember exactly, but I think I never fully "solved" it so much as I had to settle for a workaround. I think it should be put as an *issue* in MessageKit.

Comment: @Eric I found the solution, its the issue with my **IQKeyboard**. I just write only two lines code in *App Delegate* and it worked fine at my side.

Comment: @TaimoorArif Mind sharing the two lines of code you added?

Comment: @Eric you have to write this code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function of **AppDelegate** :  `IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledDistanceHandlingClasses.append(YourChatVC.self) `